# No space left on device error on Ansible Tower while executing job template

Tags: module

We are using Ansible Tower version AWX 17.1.0 with Ansible version 2.9.18.
Observing strange behaviour when executing Job of which deploys Java application on Java servers. each time launching job giving different errors and failing at different tasks with similar error like module failure and no space left on device. we verified from target hosts side there is ample amount of space. and also sometimes job is getting success. tried restart of the target hosts also no use. below are the errors faced each time. please help to fix the issue. quite surprisingly same template is working fine on other servers except these java servers.

**"msg": "\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/bin/yum", line 29, in \n    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)\n  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 375, in user_main\n    errcode = main(args)\n  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 281, in main\n    return_code = base.doTransaction()\n  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 740, in doTransaction\n    testcb = RPMTransaction(self, test=True)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 199, in **init**\n    self._setupOutputLogging(base.conf.rpmverbosity)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 222, in _setupOutputLogging\n    io_r = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()\n  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 458, in NamedTemporaryFile\n    (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)\n  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 239, in _mkstemp_inner\n    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)\nOSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/tmpOR9pdD'\n\nUnable to upload Enabled Repositories Report\n"**

FAILED! => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "application.properties", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 198.19.20.91 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "/var/SP/dyna_adm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672301679.9486687-78304-254181291127392/AnsiballZ_copy.py", line 102, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File "/var/SP/dyna_adm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672301679.9486687-78304-254181291127392/AnsiballZ_copy.py", line 89, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    with open(zipped_mod, 'wb') as modlib:\r\nIOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/ansible_copy_payload_wGKWRZ/ansible_copy_payload.zip'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}**

FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 198.19.20.90 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "/var/SP/dyna_adm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672145315.0321684-55457-255515902570625/AnsiballZ_setup.py", line 102, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File "/var/SP/dyna_adm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672145315.0321684-55457-255515902570625/AnsiballZ_setup.py", line 89, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    with open(zipped_mod, 'wb') as modlib:\r\nIOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/ansible_setup_payload_RrXk84/ansible_setup_payload.zip'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}**

I have tried on different target hosts it is working on other servers so script wise no issue. even sometimes it worked fine on these servers also but immediately when running again its failing. before it was working fine and we didnt did any changes to the server side. asnible master side no issue. target servers has enough space. really no idea why it is behaving like this

Comment: Check with `df` if some volumes of your file system have a shortage of space. Specifically check the volume the `/tmp` is on.

Comment: Thanks Eelco for the response. I checked the volumes and all are fine. I'm curious to know while ansible master executing the jobs it will push the modules for particular time and exactly at which directory it will push the modules to remote/target server

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your ansible is doing it's probably telling you the truth:

```
No space left on device
```

Login to the remote(s) server and run "df". I'm pretty sure you'll see that /var is full (100%) or close to it. If that's the case, just workout why by searching for large files (check the "du" command) and delete some of the old log files.

That should get your ansible working again.

If you still have issues, I'd be on the server while you run Ansible and watch the space fill up. you should be able to work out the cause from that. Maybe a previous task is copying/downloading a file. Could be lots of reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but I already checked while Job was running and /var folder has 450 gb space available and now without any change it fixed by itself and want to know the Root cause